# Insertion into hive ORC format table from other hive formats cannot be selected from

Tags: sql, hive, avro, orc

After creating a new hive external table in ORC format which is bucketed and inserting from another table (with the exact schema) but in Avro format (and non-bucketed) when selecting from the new table there are many errors. I put the stack of the errors here (some of them are repeated and had to delete from the end due to lack of space):

```
  Status: Failed
  Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1572541024266_0020_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1572541024266_0020_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1572541024266_0020_1_00_000000_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:365)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:33)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:151)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:62)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1191)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.ensureBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.hasNext(RecordReaderImpl.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:360)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Read past EOF for compressed stream Stream for column 44 kind DATA position: 0 length: 0 range: 0 offset: 0 limit: 0
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readFully(SerializationUtils.java:119)
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readLongLE(SerializationUtils.java:102)
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readDouble(SerializationUtils.java:98)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$DoubleTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:762)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1833)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$ListTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:2001)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:1815)
at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1184)
... 27 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1572541024266_0020_1_00_000000_1:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:365)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:33)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:151)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:62)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1191)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.ensureBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.hasNext(RecordReaderImpl.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:360)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Read past EOF for compressed stream Stream for column 44 kind DATA position: 0 length: 0 range: 0 offset: 0 limit: 0
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readFully(SerializationUtils.java:119)
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readLongLE(SerializationUtils.java:102)
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readDouble(SerializationUtils.java:98)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$DoubleTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:762)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1833)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$ListTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:2001)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:1815)
at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1184)
... 27 more
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1572541024266_0020_1_00_000000_2:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:365)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:33)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:151)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:62)
... 16 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1191)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.ensureBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.hasNext(RecordReaderImpl.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:360)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Read past EOF for compressed stream Stream for column 44 kind DATA position: 0 length: 0 range: 0 offset: 0 limit: 0
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readFully(SerializationUtils.java:119)
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readLongLE(SerializationUtils.java:102)
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readDouble(SerializationUtils.java:98)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$DoubleTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:762)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1833)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$ListTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:2001)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:1815)
at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1184)
... 27 more
], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1572541024266_0020_1_00_000000_3:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:365)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:33)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:151)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:62)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1191)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.ensureBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.hasNext(RecordReaderImpl.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:360)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Read past EOF for compressed stream Stream for column 44 kind DATA position: 0 length: 0 range: 0 offset: 0 limit: 0
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readFully(SerializationUtils.java:119)
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readLongLE(SerializationUtils.java:102)
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readDouble(SerializationUtils.java:98)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$DoubleTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:762)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1833)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$ListTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:2001)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:1815)
at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1184)
... 27 more
]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1572541024266_0020_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]
DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1572541024266_0020_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1572541024266_0020_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1572541024266_0020_1_00_000000_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:365)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:33)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:151)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:62)
... 16 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1191)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.ensureBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.hasNext(RecordReaderImpl.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:360)
... 22 more
 Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Read past EOF for compressed stream Stream for column 44 kind DATA position: 0 length: 0 range: 0 offset: 0 limit: 0
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readFully(SerializationUtils.java:119)
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readLongLE(SerializationUtils.java:102)
at org.apache.orc.impl.SerializationUtils.readDouble(SerializationUtils.java:98)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$DoubleTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:762)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1833)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$ListTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:2001)
at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:1815)
at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1184)
... 27 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1572541024266_0020_1_00_000000_1:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:185)
... 14 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: /path/000003_0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:365)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:33)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:151)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:62)
... 16 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading file:/path/000003_0
at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1191)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.ensureBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.hasNext(RecordReaderImpl.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:213)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:360)
... 22 more
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you query your avro table ? try executing group by on any column it is working fine ?

Comment: Yes I can query from the Avro table, it's a production table.

Comment: Is your insert into new table (with ORC) successful? looks like in your new table some problem with the file  ``` /path/000003_0 ``` which compression you're using on your ORC table?

Comment: It doesn't error while I insert to my new table w/ ORC format. What I did is creating a new table using the exact hql (using show create table) and replaced the avro format w/ ORC and made it bucketed. The inserted to it. I can see the added partition but when I want to select from it there is that stack of errors.